# Need help in installing Sqlectron-1.30.0.sh

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm stuck installing "**Sqlectron-1.30.0.sh**" on *Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS*

I tried the following:

```
$ chmod 777 Sqlectron-1.30.0.sh 
$ chmod +x Sqlectron-1.30.0.sh 
$ sudo ./Sqlectron-1.30.0.sh     
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

I've downloaded the *.sh* from [here](https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases/download/v1.30.0/Sqlectron-1.30.0.tar.gz).

I've already gone through all the previous posts, but none of them seems working.

Hope we make it work :)

Comment: Although I just downloaded the zip from the link you provided but I can't find `Sqlectron-1.30.0.sh`. Can you clarify where it is in zip?

Comment: Please go through the below link, you'll find multiple links:
https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases/tag/v1.30.0

BTW i got the solution, there is some issue with the .sh file. I tried using the .deb file. It works for me now.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The question is off topic as non-reproducible because it is an abandoned question.